# Matlab curve registration

Tags: matlab

I have two curves representing two functions which I shall call F(x) and G(x). I want to register, non-rigidly, one to the other and use the resulting tranformation to transform the shape of other plots. Unsuprisingly most of the scripts out there are for image registration. Is there a simpler way to transform a simple function without resorting to converting the plots to images (or hoping that one of the image algorithms works on a 2D array by dumb luck)?

I have tried simpler operations such as simply scaling the data points, but for a variety of reasons I've not found a simple scaling that works. Rigid ICP almost works but I need a stretch as well as a rotation.

Thanks.

Comment: Curve registration seems to be a relatively new concept so I doubt  you can find a script that will work out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Jim Ramsay has curve registration software here:
http://www.psych.mcgill.ca/faculty/ramsay/ramsay.html

The Shape Analysis group at FSU has software here:
http://ssamg.stat.fsu.edu/software

For the benefit of other people searching, synonyms for curve registration:
curve re-parametrization/parameterization/parameterisation/parametrisation
curve alignment